# Images are not appearing good when converted from .docx to pdf

Tags: java, pdf, apache-commons-io

I converted *.docx* file to *.pdf* file, the text is converting fine, but the images in the *.docx* file is not appearing, instead it is represented as some special characters, below is my code:

```
import com.lowagie.text.Document;    
import com.lowagie.text.Paragraph;    
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter;    
import java.io.File;    
import java.io.FileOutputStream;    
public class PDFConversion {

    /**
     * 14. This method is used to convert the given file to a PDF format 15.
     * 
     * @param inputFile
     *            - Name and the path of the file 16.
     * @param outputFile
     *            - Name and the path where the PDF file to be saved 17.
     * @param isPictureFile
     *            18.
     */

    private void createPdf(String inputFile, String outputFile, boolean isPictureFile) {
        /**
         * 22. Create a new instance for Document class 23.
         */
        Document pdfDocument = new Document();
        String pdfFilePath = outputFile;

        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(pdfFilePath);
            PdfWriter writer = null;
            writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(pdfDocument, fileOutputStream);
            writer.open();
            pdfDocument.open();

            /**
             * 34. Proceed if the file given is a picture file 35.
             */
            if (isPictureFile) {
                pdfDocument.add(com.lowagie.text.Image.getInstance(inputFile));
            }

            /**
             * 41. Proceed if the file given is (.txt,.html,.doc etc) 42.
             */

            else {
                File file = new File(inputFile);
                pdfDocument.add(new Paragraph(org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
                        .readFileToString(file)));      
            }
            pdfDocument.close();
            writer.close();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            System.out.println("Document Exception!" + exception);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        PDFConversion pdfConversion = new PDFConversion();
        pdfConversion.createPdf("C:/Users/LENOVO/Downloads/The_JFileChooser_Component.doc",
                "E:/The_JFileChooser_Component.pdf", false);
        // For other files
        // pdfConversion.createPdf("C:/shunmuga/sample.html",
        // "C:/shunmuga/sample.pdf", false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what it could be, but for some alternatives have a look at:

- **[Apose.Words Library](http://www.aspose.com/categories/java-components/aspose.words-for-java/default.aspx)** for Java it has some really cool features one of them being docx to pdf conversion by a few simple lines (and it's reliable):

  ```
  Document doc = new Document("d:/test/mydoc.docx");
  doc.Save("d:/test/Out.pdf", SaveFormat.Pdf);
  ```
- **[Docx4j](http://www.docx4java.org/svn/docx4j/trunk/docx4j/docs/Docx4j_GettingStarted.html)**
  which can be used to convert docx and many others to PDF, it does this by first using HTML/XML based on [IText](http://itextpdf.com/download.php) then converts it to a PDF (All libararies are included within docx4j, just added the itext link for completeness):

  ```
  org.docx4j.convert.out.pdf.PdfConversion c
   = new org.docx4j.convert.out.pdf.viaXSLFO.Conversion(wordMLPackage);//using xml
  // = new org.docx4j.convert.out.pdf.viaHTML.Conversion(wordMLPackage);//using html
  // = new org.docx4j.convert.out.pdf.viaIText.Conversion(wordMLPackage);//using itext libs
  ```

If that's not enough it has [sample source code](http://www.docx4java.org/svn/docx4j/trunk/docx4j/src/main/java/org/docx4j/samples/CreatePdf.java) for you to try.

- **[xdocreport](http://code.google.com/p/xdocreport/)**  also comes with a lot of [samples](http://code.google.com/p/xdocreport/downloads/detail?name=docxandvelocity.converters-0.9.8-sample.zip) for conversion (haven't downloaded them, but it should have the doc/docx to PDF converter source)

Comment: +1 excellent buddy, i used docx4j and was able to create pdf files perfectly. i have to wait till the bounty ends whether any body provide me some more suggestions.