# docx4java PDF conversion: right method for images?

Tags: pdf, ms-word, docx4j

I'm using the docx4java library (http://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j) to create Word documents. Now I'd also like to use it to create corresponding PDF documents.

I've seen a couple of resources about this, notably [images are not appearing good when converted from .docx to pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529499/images-are-not-appearing-good-when-converted-from-docx-to-pdf) and http://www.docx4java.org/forums/pdf-output-f27/how-to-convert-docx-to-pdf-t218.html. But these seem like they may be outdated.  All of them list 3 methods of using docx4j for this conversion: html, iText, and XSLFO. But there's no indication of which of these methods are supported in the current (late-2015) version of docx4j or which are best for handling embedded images (of which I've got a lot).

Anyone have any *up-to-date* pointers on using docx4j in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the [sample code](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/ConvertOutPDF.java), which uses XSL FO and Apache FOP.

Plutext (with which I'm affiliated) now also offers a commercial converter which takes a completely different approach.  If you'd like to try that, you can do so at http://converter-eval.plutext.com/